# Opposite function of strpos to grab values that do not match a specific pattern in a string or array

Tags: php, arrays, match, strpos

What is a function I can use that's basically the opposite of doing

```
if(strpos($array['some_key'], $value)!==false) {
    that means there's a match and confinue
}
```

I basically want to loop through two arrays and grab the ones that don't have a match to the `$value` in `$array`.

```
    $array = 

      Array
            (
            [0] => GPPZ20
            [1] => GPPZ45
            [2] => GPPZ75
            [3] => GPPZH20
            [4] => GPPZH45
       )


     $codes = 

        Array
    (
     [0] => Array
      (
        [count] => 1
        [code] => GPPZH20SWYE4A2VZU
        [amount] => 20
    )

    )

      Array
     (
       [0] => Array
      (
        [count] => 1
        [code] => GPPZH2077434178J6
        [amount] => 20
    )

      )

    Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [count] => 17
        [code] => PMMC4
        [amount] => 25
    )

)

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
        [code] => GPPZH2052910M8V62
        [amount] => 20
    )

)

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
        [code] => GPPZH45B3116LD1VW
        [amount] => 45
    )

 )
```

so what i want to do is grab all the ones in the $codes array where the $codes['code'] value does not match any of the ones in the $array value.

right now i have the ones that match and grabbing those by doing

```
  foreach($codes as $code) {
      foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
         if(strpos($code['code'], $value)!==false) {
              //it matches grab those values
         }
       }
  }
```

I basically now need something like this to grab the ones that do not match

Comment: Just chage the `!==` to `===`.

Comment: I tried that it doesnt work it still returns all the items that match my $value pattern as well as the rest that dont. I just want to grab the ones that dont match

Comment: I have a suspicion that you don't actually want the inverse of `strpos`. Can you post example input and output values? I.e. what would the result be for the inputs `$array = array('abc', 'x'=>'cde'}` and `$value='c';`?

Comment: Show us actual code that you have tried that doesn't work and then we can help diagnose that code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `array_filter` function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php e.g.:

```
function myFilter($val){ return strpos('foo', $val) === false; }
$array = array("foobar", "foo", "bar");
var_dump(array_filter($array, myFilter));
```

You can also use `preg_match` method instead of `strpos`.